# insert into a table from another table with different columns

Tags: sql, insert, inner-join

I have two tables A and B, so that B ⊂ A (it means every column of B is in A, but A has more columns that there is not in B)

Table A is empty and I want to insert the Values of B into A. how can I do that?

for Example:
A:
[image]

B:
[image]

Comment: `INSERT INTO a SELECT colx, coly,, ... FROM b`.

Comment: should I select all of columns from b here?

Comment: Only the ones you want to be inserted into a.

Comment: However, copying data between tables is generally a bad idea. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: but I get error:

Comment: Error report -
SQL Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-117, SQLSTATE=42802, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.26.14

Comment: I added some new columns to a table and trying to import values from old table

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work I think

```
INSERT INTO A (load, Roll, dest)
SELECT load, Roll, dest
FROM B
```

Comment: I get this error:
Error report -
SQL Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-407, SQLSTATE=23502, SQLERRMC=TBSPACEID=2, TABLEID=2, COLNO=0, DRIVER=4.26.14

Comment: please check the columns you are defining here. Because this error means the column given is not present in table.

Comment: I had to select all columns of B, only so it worked.

Comment: oh ok got it. Glad it helped.

Comment: not working, table A has 40 column table B has 10 column with same name as table A. trying to add table B data to table A. it shows error of column names except 10 column